# flask appbuilder how to pass data to actions - solved

Tags: python, flask, flask-appbuilder

i have a Flask-AppBuilder web page, I want to create a new page for our staff to use for send message to telegram

[image]

Model:

```
class Push(Model):
__tablename__ = 'push'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
content = Column(String(255), nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
  return self.name
```

View :

```
   def testaction(self,Push):
        result = db.session.query(Push).all()
        return str(result)
        bot_token = 'TOKEN'
        bot_chatID = 'ID'
        send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message
        response = requests.get(send_text)
        return response.json()
    bot_message = testaction(result)
    print(bot_message)
```

but had  a error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '[hi]'
```

AND does not send the message to telegram

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't see in which line of code you get erorr, and I don't see where you use SQLAlchemy so it could generate error. So there is no enough information and question is useless.

Comment: BTW: don't use the same name for `class Push` and for variable `def testaction(self,Push):` - it is missleading and sometimes it can makes problem. And PEP8 suggests to use `CamelCaseNames` only for classes. and `lower_case_names` for variables - ie `def testaction(self, push):`. See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: BTW: maybe you should use `query(column_name=value)` - for example `query(content=push)` or `query(id=push)`. Probably `query(push)` doesn't know which column check in database.

Comment: it seems  all your problem is that you use database in wrong way and you have to read documentation - ie. [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/)

Comment: Thank All  , now i use ,now can dispaly the select field data  and  I study now to pass to  telegram ```class PushView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Push)
    
    @action("testaction","Do something on this record","Do you really want to?","fa-rocket")

    def testaction(self,tel):
        return str(tel)```

Comment: I rather expected something like `result = Push.query.filter_by(content=tel).first()`. Eventually `result = db.session.query(Push).filter_by(content=tel).first()`